# How to use hid object on multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am using rust to interact with a StreamDeck using the hid (https://crates.io/crates/hid) library.

I want to:

- Read from the hid device to register button presses and releases.
- Write to the device to set images on the buttons.

Since reading from the device is blocking, I want to do this on different threads.

For interacting with hid devices, it creates a `Handle` (https://github.com/meh/rust-hid/blob/master/src/handle.rs#L8) which cannot be moved between threads because it contains a `ptr: *mut hid_device`.

```
(the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut c_void`)
```

Is there some way I can use the handle from multiple threads? On one I would read and on the other I would write.

Comment: FYI, that crate seems to be abandoned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options potentially, but I'd recommend to use channels, for example [tokio's mpsc channels](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.16.1/tokio/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html).

The idea is to create a dedicated thread for talking with the device, and only use Handle in that thread. The events and commands that you want to receive or send can be posted to the respective channel, and handled in your main "controller" thread.

Check out [this tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/channels).